# Listview used with ObservableCollection doesn't load last item properly when deleting from same page

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms, observablecollection, xamarin.forms.listview

I am trying to display a list of students in listview. I have used ObservableCollection as ItemSource for my listview and when I try to add to the Collection it displayes in UI successfully. Problem arises when I try to remove item from collection I have attached images below. collection length decreses by 1 which is correct but that element is not displayed at all. (if I have `n` elements in my collection before deleting then also same behaviour is found in that only last element is not displayed properly and all first `n-1` elements are displayed as expected)

[xamarin forum link for question](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/150130/listview-used-with-observablecollection-doesnt-load-last-item-properly-when-deleting-from-same-page#latest)

Please visit above link for detail visual description of the issue.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Hi Gaurav, thank you for your question. To get a better understanding of your question I think it would help if you edit your question and add some code that you use to show us how your ListView is built up, how the items get in the ListView and what code you use to delete the items

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, you don’t put some code about how to delete item from Observablecollection, I guess that you may have some issue when deleting item, I do one sample about remove item from ListView, you can take a look:

```
 <ListView
            IsPullToRefreshEnabled="true"
            ItemSelected="OnSelection"
            ItemTapped="OnTap"
            ItemsSource="{Binding}"
            Refreshing="OnRefresh">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <ViewCell.ContextActions>
                            <!--
                                CommandParameter is the command to pass to the clicked event handler. Because these are menu items,
                                not cells managed by the ListView, CommandParameter is neccesary to determine which
                                cell the context action was taken on.
                            -->
                            <MenuItem
                                Clicked="OnMore"
                                CommandParameter="{Binding Name}"
                                Text="More" />
                            <MenuItem
                                Clicked="OnDelete"
                                CommandParameter="{Binding Name}"
                                IsDestructive="true"
                                Text="Delete" />
                        </ViewCell.ContextActions>
                        <StackLayout Padding="15,0">
                            <Label Text="{Binding Name}" />
                            <Label Text="{Binding Age}" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>



[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class Page2 : ContentPage
{
    public static ObservableCollection<student> items { get; set; }
    public Page2 ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
        items = new ObservableCollection<student>()
        {
            new student(){Name="Cherry",Age=12},
        new student() { Name = "Nock", Age = 13 },
        new student() { Name = "Mattew", Age = 13 }


        };
        this.BindingContext = items;
    }

    private void OnSelection(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.SelectedItem == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        DisplayAlert("Item Selected", ((student)e.SelectedItem).Name.ToString(), "Ok");
    }

    private void OnTap(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
    {
        DisplayAlert("Item Tapped", ((student)e.Item).Name.ToString(), "Ok");
    }

    private void OnRefresh(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var list = (ListView)sender;
        //put your refreshing logic here
        var itemList = items.Reverse().ToList();
        items.Clear();
        foreach (var s in itemList)
        {
            items.Add(s);
        }
        //make sure to end the refresh state
        list.IsRefreshing = false;
    }

    private void OnMore(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var item = (MenuItem)sender;

        DisplayAlert("More Context Action", item.CommandParameter.ToString() + " more context action", "OK");
    }

    private void OnDelete(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var item = (MenuItem)sender;
        student s = (from itm in items
                         where itm.Name == item.CommandParameter.ToString()
                         select itm)
              .FirstOrDefault<student>();
        items.Remove(s);

    }
}

public class student
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Int32 Age { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Cherry,

I have solved this issue on Android but **same solution is not working in iOS**.

Previously I was using Object of ObservableCollection in my ViewModel and using method to return same instance to listView.Itemsource like below,

In ViewModel:

```
private static ObservableCollection<Student> listofStds = new ObservableCollection<Student>();

public static ObservableCollection<Student> GetStudents()
{return listofStds;}
```

In View:

```
listView.ItemsSource = StudentsViewModel.GetStudents();
```

Now I have chnged above code with

In ViewModel:

```
class StudentsViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged

private static List<Student> listofStds { get; set; }
public ObservableCollection<Student> listofStd
{
   get
   {
       return new ObservableCollection<Student>(listofStds);
   }
   set
  {
       //listofStds = value;
       OnPropertyChanged("listofStd");
   }
}
```

In View:

```
StudentsViewModel viewModel = new StudentsViewModel();

BindingContext = viewModel;
listView.SetBinding(ListView.ItemsSourceProperty, "listofStd");
```

In iOS, when I run same code below given messages are displayed in Debug Window.

```
2019-02-13 16:52:14.323411+0530 NewStudentApp.iOS[90746:419211] SecTaskLoadEntitlements failed error=22 cs_flags=200, pid=90746
2019-02-13 16:52:14.323666+0530 NewStudentApp.iOS[90746:419211] SecTaskCopyDebugDescription: NewStudentApp.iO[90746]/0#-1 LF=0
```